Google oauth2 requires client_secret while using PKCA
I'm having some issues with the google login flow while usign byteowls/capacitor-oauth2 library in an ionic + angular app.
The same plugin works fine for microsoft and okta, but when trying to use it with google I'm getting an error when retrieving the actual oauth token. This is the config I'm using:
{
    authorizationBaseUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    accessTokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    scope: 'email profile',
    resourceUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me',
    responseType: 'code',
    pkceEnabled: true,
    logsEnabled: true,
    web: {
        pkceEnabled: true,
        appId: '<<google OAuth client ID>>',
        redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/',
        windowOptions: 'height=600,left=0,top=0',
    },
};

I get to through the google login flow, get asked for permissions and when the token endpoint is called
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: <<google OAuth client ID>>
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8100/
code: <<code>>
code_verifier: <<code_verifier>>

but the response I get is
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "client_secret is missing."
}

why is it requiring me a client_secret considering that I'm using the PKCE flow with code_challenge?
Has someone faced this issue and/or found a workaround?

I think if you setup your app with a client_secret it'll be required.  Not sure why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724690/using-google-oidc-with-code-flow-and-pkce

Yeah I run into a lot of posts saying that it's required and no one really knows why, so far I decided to change to @codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth so far but would be good to be able to use the same library for every provider
