Blazor WASM OIDC authentication with Google fail
I've implemented a Blazor WASM application wiht Google authentication as described
here.
If I select "Log in", I get redirected to Google and I can insert my username and password.
At that point Google redirect to the RedirectUri (/authentication/login-callback).
This cause the Blazor SPA to reload, which is expected.
At that point I can see (from Edge Dev Tools) the AuthenticationService.js library to issue a token request to Google, but the request fails.

My understanding so far:

I'm using an Authentication Code Flow with PKCE: by design, this does not store the client_secret on the client, nor sends it to the IP.
if I change the ResponseCode to "id_token" as suggested here, authentication complete. But, this way, I'm using Implicit Flow, which is no longer recommended for security reasons.

Thank you.

Unfortunately, google oauth2 "web application" client doesn't really support code flow with PKCE even for now https://stackoverflow.com/a/63275535/20240963. 
But the "UWP" client support PKCE https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#step1-code-verifier. So there is a workaround that you create a "UWP" client, then the authentication will success.
Credentials -> Create credentials -> OAuth client ID -> UWP

You could use this "UWP" client for Blazor WASM. And the store ID can be whatever.
